# Simple structured data/note management tool

Tags: windows, note-taking, information-management, data

I have a project for which I need to add structured data and then be able to filter and sort for display or export.

The data will have mostly single-valued key:value pairs - usually alphanumeric strings, but along with a couple of date and numeral fields and also a couple of multi-valued fields (like tags). Some URLs too.

I would then like to setup a simple formatting for the display of each entry or export to a neat-looking plaintext or self-contained HTML (PDF acceptable). Combining filters is preferred, so e.g.

```
Show all entries where a tag is X and date is between A and B.
```

This is for my own local, offline use and not for a commercial project, so it doesn't need to inter-operate with anything else or work well with the web.

I don't want to use Excel and am hoping to not have to install a dedicated solution like MySQL. That's too involved for what I need to do. I'd like a single app/solution that can create a flat-file DB, ideally human-readable, and perform the display/export that I'd like, on Windows 7.